# How to setup local docker environment for AWS Glue Schema Registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-glue

I would like to setup my local docker environment for development using AWS Glue Schema Registry. I tried to search and didn't find any useful information.

Comment: What does docker have to do with glue schema registry?

Comment: @luk2302 when you want to run your system locally before deploying it to AWS - docker is generally the preferred way to reproduce a production-like setup.

Comment: @luk2302 I assume the op means to be able to run without having to configure AWS access for development. For many AWS services, there are various dockerized versions - but not for the schema registry. 
And using Confluent locally and Glue in production-like environments seems like an undesirable overhead.